# Required Client Certificate asp.net core web.api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates, mtls

I want to implement client certificate authentication in my web api. I followed the MSDN documentation and tried other examples on the web. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

The page can be reached with the certificate mode "noCertificate". But when I implement the following line I get this error.

```
 opt.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
```

[image]

Here is my code. Maybe someone can spot my mistake. Actually, I would expect the browser to open the certificate selection window.

Programm.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using TestClientCert.Validator;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(opt =>
    {


        opt.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;

    });
});

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddTransient<MyCertificateValidationService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyCertificateValidationService>();

                if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                {
                    context.Success();
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Fail("invalid cert");
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.Fail("invalid cert");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

MyCertificateValidationService.cs

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace TestClientCert.Validator
{
    public class MyCertificateValidationService
    {
        public bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
        {
            string[] allowedThumbprints = { "B30D884E44EC218513CF2A5CA246F0AFA1DD8E9B", "6ECB2E563B9129C72215EE00686CAA95FBC5BEC6" };
            if (allowedThumbprints.Contains(clientCertificate.Thumbprint))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestClientCert.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get() => "Welcome to Narnia";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I would expect the browser to open the certificate selection window.

I test your code, you maybe need to use PowerShell Commands to create Certificates and add Root CA to CertMgr and add Child Certificate in Chrome Browser.

***Step1 Use PowerShell Commands to create Certificates***

Certificate Authentication requires 2 types of Certificates, these are:Certification Authority (CA) and Child Certificate.

**1.Creating Certification Authority (CA) in PowerShell**

First open the PowerShell as an adminstrator. Then run the following 3 commands one by one:

Command 1: Create Self Signed Certificate

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost", "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(20) -FriendlyName "Rlocalhost" -KeyUsageProperty All -KeyUsage CertSign, CRLSign, DigitalSignature
```

This command will create the self-signed Certificate Authority and provide it’s `thumbprint`. Keep this thumbprint safe as we will use it to create child certificate.

Command 2: Set the password for the Certificate(I am keeping the password 1234.)

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText
```

Command 3: Export the Certificate in a PFX file

We will now use the password which we set earlier and use it along with the thumbprint to export the certificate in a .pfx file.

Run the below command but before that change the text `"thumbprint"` with the thumbprint which you got earlier.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\"thumbprint" | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath D:\root.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

The command will export the certificate authority file called root.pfx on the “D” drive.(Note: you can use your other drive too, ex: `C:\root.pfx`.)

**2.Creating Child Certificate in PowerShell**

Let us create Child Certificate from root CA. So run the following 4 commands
one by one. Note that:

In the first command change the text`"ca thumbprint"` with the thumbprint of root certificate which you got earlier.

After running the second command you will get the thumbprint of the child certificate. You have to change the text `"thumbprint"` in the fourth command with this thumbprint. These 4 commands are given below.

```
$rootcert = ( Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\"ca thumbprint" )
 
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "localhost" -Signer $rootcert -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(20) -FriendlyName "Clocalhost"
 
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText
 
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\"thumbprint" | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath D:\child.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

The child certificate file called child.pfx will be created on the “D” drive.In the following image I have shown both the certificate files that are created on my D drive.

[image]

***Step2  Add Root CA to CertMgr***

Windows uses a utility called CertMgr to manage certificates. Search for “CertMgr” or “Manage Computer Certificates” in the windows search to open this utility. Next, right click on the “Certificates” folder which is under the “Trusted Root Certification Authorities” and select `All Tasks ➤ Import` and browse to the root.pfx file on the D drive.

Click on the Next button to reach the next screen where you are asked to enter the private key (password). Recall we used “1234” as the password.Continue the process and your root CA certificate will be added.

***Step3 Add Child Certificate in Chrome Browser***

Now we will add the child certificate to chrome browser. So go to settings and then click the Security section under “Privacy and security”. Here you will find Now we will add the child certificate to chrome browser. So go to settings and then click the Security section under “Privacy and security”. Here you will find `Manage device Certificates`, click on it to open a dialog window.

In this window make sure you are on the “Personal” tab and then click the Import button. Simply import the child.pfx file. As previously, enter the password 1234 when asked.

[image]
Now once again run your app on Visual Studio and open the url of the web api. This time chrome will ask you to select the child certificate.

**result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I had found the same instructions on the Internet and have already carried them out several times. I have found the solution to my problem. Sophos seems to have blocked the request for the client certificate. After I deactivated the firewall, the certificate is requested.
But I have another question. I don't understand the validation of the certificates. If I set breakpoints in the validator class, I never get there when debugging. In the "Program.cs" class, I commented out all my code for validation.  Only "requiredCertificate" line. still seems to work. Why?